# Meaning of 这么说 in the conversation

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

> A:她未婚夫不愿意让她工作了。
>   B:这么说，结婚以后她就不工作了。
>   A:对。

My questions are

(1) What is the meaning of 这么说 in this conversation?

(2) In addition, does 这么说 have any other meanings? Can you give me some examples?

Comment: 这么说 is probably like "that is to say" in English. It can be taken as the omission of 照你这么说 -- according to what you have told me/(you have said).

Comment: Here's one way of using 这么说; https://youtu.be/sLWls1V2QQs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *(1) What is the meaning of 这么说 in this conversation?*

'这么'  means 'so/ this way/ like this'

'这么**说**' means '**saying** so' = "**according to** so" (with this reason) in this context.

You can simply use 'accordingly' , 'consequently', 'therefore' or 'so' instead

E.g. "So, after she got married, she stopped working"

> (2) *In addition, does 这么说 have any other meanings? Can you give me some examples?*

这么说 literally means "say /said /saying so" and you can use it literally. e.g. "他这么说" (he said so); 人們是這麼說的 (people are saying so)

Comment: If I say 我这么说, does it mean "I have said that!"?

Comment: 我是这么说的 = That is what I said; " -->  (这么 means so. That is what I said)

Comment: 我是这么说過 = I have said that

Comment: the phrase 他这么说 needs more context to pinpoint the meaning. It can mean 'He said it this way" or "he said this"

Answer (score 1):

这么说，followed by a sentence, means it is a hypothesis but if what you said is right, this hypothesis should be correct with a very high possibility.

这么说 = 如果你说的是对的，那么......

```
A:她未婚夫不愿意让她工作了。
B:如果你说的是对的，那么结婚以后她就不工作了。
A:对。

A:非常遗憾，他的父母都死于这次车祸了。
B:这么说（如果你说的是对的，那么）他就是个孤儿了。
A:对。

A:他去美国了工作了。（he has been in the US and worked there）
B:这么说，他的英语一定说得很好。（If what you said is true, (I guess) his English must be good enough）
A:不，他的英语并不好，不过他是去做中文老师，所以我猜他应该没问题。(No, ...)
```

Comment: Thanks for examples. If I say 我这么说, does it mean "I have said that!"?

Comment: @Jenny  Yes. They are totally different. 我这么说，是因为XXX：I said that because XXX.